# Use Regular Expression for an URL

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

I have been banging my head for this issue but to no result.

I have a URL like this :

```
http://1.1.1.1:8080/Offers
```

Then I click on a **Create** button. It becomes :

```
http://1.1.1.1:8080/newaccount/Country/Region/State/2016/11/12/offer-111111.html
```

The `2016/11/12/offer-111111` portion of the URL keeps changing at each run.

Any ideas how I should use a regular expression from `newaccount/Country/Region/State/2016/11/12/offer-111111`, so that I could use this after `1.1.1.1:8080/`, which would mean it would run irrespective of the changes in the URL?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler not all characters are valid for a url. ".*" would include spaces and non-ascii characters etc, which i don't believe are valid

Comment: 1.1.1.1:8080/[^"<>\^`\x{0000)-\x{0020}\x{007b}-\x{FFFF}]

Comment: Thank you Engineer14. I will try this out.

Comment: Thank you TessellatingHeckler

Answer (score 1):

**As per your description:-**

You are getting the second URL i.e.

> http://1.1.1.1:8080/newaccount/Country/Region/State/2016/11/12/offer-111111.html

as a response of first URL hit.

So you can use below mentioned **Regular Expression**

> newaccount/Country/Region/State/(.*?).html

and after that append the reference name in place of `2016/11/12/offer-111111` like this

`http://1.1.1.1:8080/newaccount/Country/Region/State/${RegEX_RefrenceName}.html`

Comment: Thank you Vikas, i will try This. Thank you. I will get back once i am done trying with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
http://1.1.1.1:8080/newaccount/Country/Region/State/\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d/offer-\d+.html
```

Comment: Thank you Bohemian, i will try This. Thank you. I will get back once i am done trying with this.

Comment: Do you need to capture any of the URL (to redirect etc)?

Comment: Yes . In a way yes.              So the first url     -     "1.1.1.1:8080/offers"    would change to      "1.1.1.1:8080/newaccount/Country/Region/State/2016/01/16/offer-123456.html" after i click on create button .                    In this page, i would need to enter some data.         I use a load testing tool, which if i record it gets recorded as in case of the 2nd URL.   but when i playback   --  it would playback as the portion of the URL , "2016/01/16/offer-123456.html"  , would have dynamically changed ..

Comment: For eg: Now it would have become (while playing back the recorded script) -- "2016/02/16/offer-987654.html" thus failing the script as the URL does not match. I hope i answered your question . Thanks.